# Using Jquery tabs with JSP pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery tabs with jquery-ui 1.9.2, I have to make jsp pages as my tabbed pages, her is what I have,

```
<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
          <li><a href="page1.jsp">Page1</a></li>
          <li><a href="page2.jsp">Page2</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Is this the proper way ? I ask because, when I do this, the tabs don't retain any changes I make(displaying tables using ajax) on the jsp pages when I switch between tabs, also it misbehaves sometimes, as in my datepicker and submit's don't fire until I refresh the main page. There are no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Please Follow the link.

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

In which you can get all the info about jQuery with coding.

Comment: I am already doing that, my tabs are being loaded, but why does the content vanish when I switch, also why do my buttons stop working ?